# How to instantiate a class object with a 2 dimensional array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, instantiation

I'm trying to insantiate an object with a 2 dimensional array but the following code doesn't seem to work:

```
class Board {
  constructor(row,col){
    this.board=[];
    for (var i=0; i<row; i++){
      for (var y=0; y<col; y++){
        this.board[i][y]=0;
      }
    }
  }
}

var board = new Board(10,10);
```

https://jsbin.com/worepeb/edit?js,console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to init the sub-array before you can fill it with numbers - `this.board[i] = [];`:

```js
class Board {
  constructor(row,col){
    this.board=[];
    for (var i=0; i<row; i++){
      this.board[i] = []; // init this.board[i]
      for (var y=0; y<col; y++){
        this.board[i][y]=0;
      }
    }
  }
}

var board = new Board(10,10);

console.log(board);
```

You can also use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to init the board:

```js
class Board {
  constructor(row,col){
    this.board = Array.from({ length: row }, () => 
      Array.from({ length: col }, () => 0)
    );
  }
}

const board = new Board(10,10);

console.log(board);
```